# Printing tuple indexed [:1] works, but [0] produces TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing, tuples

```
fhand = open(raw_input('Enter a file name: '))
counts = dict()
words = []
for lines in fhand:
    if lines.startswith('From') and not lines.startswith('From:'):
        words = lines.split()
        if words[1] not in counts:
            counts[words[1]] = 1
        else:
            counts[words[1]] += 1

lst = list()
for key, val in counts.items():
    lst.append((val, key))
lst.sort(reverse=True)
for key, val in lst[0]:
    print key, val
```

The part in question is:

```
for key, val in lst[0]:
    print key, val
```

This gives me: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. I have figured out that for some reason this does work:

input:

```
for key, val in lst[:1]:
    print key, val
```

output:

```
Enter a file name: mbox-short.txt
5 cwen@iupui.edu
```

I'm just trying to figure out why exactly this works but not [0]. And as always, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to realize the difference between `[0]` and `[:1]`

What `[0]` does is return to you the value that is stored at index 0 of the list.

On the other hand, when you do `[:1]`, you are *slicing* the list, meaning you're getting all the elements of the list with index from 0 (inclusive) up to  1 (non inclusive).

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

> All slice operations return a new list containing the requested elements.

So when you slice a list, you're also getting back a list. And lists, being iterable types, can be -well- iterated! And this is true even if they contain only one element.

When you do `for key, val in lst[0]`, you're trying to iterate a single value, the one that is stored at index 0 in `lst`. However, when instead of [0] you do `[:1]`, what is returned isn't a single value but a *range* of values. In your case it may contain only one value, but it is still a range and therefore can be iterated in a `for` loop.

For a simpler explanation, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/7662085) great answer by [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) on how list slices work.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer and the links you left helped clear up a lot of confusion I've been trying to work through for a while now. Tyty!

Comment: @Sty This: "you're getting all the elements of the list with index up to (and including) 1" doesn't sound right. To me that would mean that `[:1]` should return two elements. This is not the case, however, the newly sliced list contain only one element. But it _is_ a list, though, so it is still different from a single element.

Comment: @Sty No, it is the other way around. You get everything up to, but not including `end`. Have you tried it in a python interpreter?

Answer (score 4):

Consider something like:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
```

`lst[0]` is an `int` (`1`) and an `int` is not iterable.  However, `lst[:1]` *is another `list`* and therefore it *is* iterable.

In your case, you have a list of 2-tuples.  so `lst[0]` is a 2-tuple -- Which is iterable.  However, iterating over the 2-tuple will give you individual items which are not iterable and therefore cannot be unpacked into `key, val`.  On the flip side, `lst[:1]` gives you a new list that holds 2-tuples.  The list can be iterated and then the 2-tuples *can* be unpacked into `key`/`value` pairs.

Comment: @wim -- Yeah, I added that to the answer just a minute ago.

Answer (score 3):

`list[0]` returns an object, the element at index 0, but the for in loop syntax expects something iterable like a list of objects.

`list[:1]` slices the list into a new list that just includes the first element and so it will work.